# CrossSecureStorage properties being cleared when application exits

Tags: xamarin, mvvmcross

I'm using Plugin.SecureStorage from https://github.com/sameerkapps/SecureStorage.

I'm trying to store data like username and password after successfully logs in the application. However, whenever I close my application, the data I saved from the CrossSecureStorage are cleared.

Comment: Umm, I am not sure which plugin is this but are you using iOS simulators?https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/77760/ios-10-keychain Secondly, you should never save passwords it's against PCI compliance.

Comment: You might want to look at using Xamarin's Secure Storage : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/secure-storage?context=xamarin%2Fxamarin-forms&tabs=android